# How to redirect a user from the root path to a specific base path in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-application-gateway

I have an AKS cluster with an internal load balancer (NGINX) with a private IP address. For public access, the cluster is fronted by an Azure Application Gateway that routes traffic to the internal load balancer. Assume the Application Gateway is given the domain `https://myapp.mycompany.com` and the internal load balancer is given `https://cluster.aks-ingress.myapp.mycompany.com`.

I have several applications hosted in the cluster, one of which is the Home app which is given the path `/home` using an Ingress. If I access `https://myapp.mycompany.com/home` from my browser then the request is routed correctly to the Home application.

My requirement is that if someone tries to access `https://myapp.mycompany.com` in their browser they should be redirected to `https://myapp.mycompany.com/home`, since the former does not have any associated application and simply returns a 404. I have searched for ways to do this using Application Gateway to no avail. I have also tried using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root` annotation but that redirects the user to a URL containing the internal host name (i.e. `https://cluster.aks-ingress.myapp.mycompany.com/home`).

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarily solved this by creating a deployment, service and ingress at the root path (i.e. /) just to serve up an HTML page with some JavaScript to do the redirect:
`window.location.href = “/home”;`.

My guess is there's probably a better way to do this.